# What's an antonym for the slang "straight up"?

Tags: word-request, synonyms, antonyms

What's an antonym for the slang "straight up"?

> He was straight up roasted by the President during the meeting.

I mean to say "indirectly" or something along the same line.

Comment: "Obliquely" would be an option.

Answer (score 1):

You might use ‘covertly’ or ‘implicitly’. ‘Indirectly’ would work well too.

For some slang terms in keeping with ‘straight up’, you might hear ‘kind of’ or ‘sort of’, which kind of imply that whether or not he was actually roasted might be up for debate.

Comment: Absolutely. Other slangy ways of asserting some vagueness might include "basically" or "more or less." In fact, since a person would not use the phrase "straight up" in formal writing or speaking, one might even see "kinda" and "sorta" used in lieu of their correct forms.